# Anchor butcher block table to concrete wall?

Tags: table

I want to build a workbench using an end grain butcher block table top perhaps mounted on 4 6x6 oak beams. I still need to anchor it to the wall to make it really sturdy and how to do this is tricky question. One obvious approach is use angles, but I am not convinced that is as sturdy as possible and ordinary angles usually deviate from 90 degrees. Another idea would be to use 45-degree braces, but then I have rods underneath the table which could interfere with shelving for example. Another idea would be to make a steel girdle which would go all the way around the edge of the table and then bolt the girdle to the wall.

The way I am kind of leaning is to use a backplate. The way this would work is that a hot rolled iron plate 1/2-inch thick and 12" high would be bolted to the concrete along the length of the table, then it would be drilled and tapped to receive bolts. Then cast iron machinist angles would be bolted to the plate and to the bottom of the table. These type  of angles are incredibly strong and are 90-degrees to a high tolerance. The drawback to this approach is that it is expensive and time consuming.

Note that the table will be used to support heavy machine tools and needs to be rigid and not subject to vibration.

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: I would use angle or a ledger board anchored to the wall, if an angle / ledger won't hold it would be doubtful that triangle braces would do much better for support of the back then some front legs.

Comment: I would like to see a drawing of what you propose